# SAPRFC using PHP

Tags: php, saprfc

I am working on a project that would allow upload to SAP using PHP.

I used the code:

// Call-Function

```
$parameters = array(

    array("IMPORT", "ZMM_", "*"),
    //array("EXPORT", "*", array()),
    array("TABLE", "IMT_", array())
  );

$result = $sap->callFunction('ZMM_', $parameters);
```

I want to display the contents of the table but is getting an error message for
import parameter. can anyone please help me to solve this?

Thanks

Answer (score 5):

It seems that you use this - https://github.com/sensational/php-saprfc/blob/php7/saprfc.php - php callFunction implementation for a call to a **user defined function ZMM_** ( a SAP function that is in the Z_ namespace and which you implemented in SAP by yourself - for ZMM_ does standardly not exist in the system and all existing ZMM* are not remote enabled), which holds a table, in SAP over SAP rfcsdk. 
[image: not!!! remote enabled]

1. Did you remote enable this function(like for example the one shown in pic1 RFC_READ_TABLE is) that you built by your own in SAP? If not it can't work together with SAP rfcsdk
   [image: rfc remote enabled]
2. If yes - your parameters can't be right. This is an example for a tyical call to an existing rfc function in SAP within that framework, that you !!seem!!(*I only can guess it, for you do not explain it*) to use.

P.S.:
If you don't use a php framework for E. Koucky's saprfc 1.4.1 extension dll (*which you !!seem!! to use*) you can use direct calls, which means direct calls in the compiled extension[php_functions]. I indicated the direct calls with ****....****. You can directly call like that:

```
 ...
                            // router string 
 $LOGIN = array ("ASHOST"=>"/H/xx.xx.xx.com/S/port/W/xx/H/localhost",   
               "SYSNR"   =>"00",
               "CLIENT"  =>"800",
               "USER"    =>"xxxxxxxx",
               "PASSWD"  =>"xxxxxxxx",  
               "LANG"    =>"E");
    ...
    $table="T100";
    $criteria="SPRSL EQ 'E' AND TEXT GE 'Must e' AND TEXT LT 'N'";
    $options=array("TEXT"=>$criteria);
    ...
    $rfc = ****saprfc_open**** ($LOGIN);
    $fce = ****saprfc_function_discover****($rfc,"RFC_READ_TABLE"); 
    ...
    // set import parameters 
    saprfc_import ($fce,"DELIMITER","*");
    saprfc_import ($fce,"NO_DATA","");
    saprfc_import ($fce,"QUERY_TABLE",$table);
    saprfc_import ($fce,"ROWCOUNT","");
    saprfc_import ($fce,"ROWSKIPS","");

    saprfc_table_init ($fce,"FIELDS");
    saprfc_table_init ($fce,"OPTIONS");
    saprfc_table_init ($fce,"DATA");
    // options look at the top -> $criteria
    ****saprfc_table_append**** ($fce,"OPTIONS", $options); 
    ...
     for($i=1; $i<=$data_row;$i++)
        {
            $DATA[$i] = ****saprfc_table_read**** ($fce,"DATA",$i);
            $ex = explode("*",$DATA[$i]["WA"]);
    ...
```

You can find a working saprfc extension for php-7.1.11-nts-x32 together with SAPGUI 7.4 (rfcsdk 7.4) here
https://sourceforge.net/projects/saprfcsdk/files/PHP%207.1.11%20NTS%20VC14%20%20SAP%20GUI%207.4%20-%20x32%20%20NUC/

You can grab the directly callable extension-functions by using

```
$extensions= get_loaded_extensions();
$functions=array();

foreach($extensions as $ext) 
{
    if($ext=="saprfc-gimba")
    {
        echo "<font size='4' color='green'>".$ext."</font><font size='2' color='green'> ist geladen<br></font>";
        echo "<font size='1' color='green'>vorhandene Funktionen:<br></font>";
        $functions =  get_extension_funcs($ext);
    }
}
foreach($functions as $text) 
{
    echo "<font size='1' color='green'>$text<br></font>";
}
```

Then you get that result
[image: directly callable php saprfc extension functions]

Here you have a table query from table TFDIR which returns all the RFC_* functions in the system. If you set FMODE EQ 'R' you get all functions of the system which are remotely callable.

```
$table="TFDIR";
    $criteria="FUNCNAME GE 'RFC_' AND FUNCNAME LT 'RFC_ZZZZ'";
    $options=array("TEXT"=>$criteria);

    $LOGIN = array ("ASHOST"=>"/H/sapx.x.x.com/S/port/W/x/H/localhost",
               "SYSNR" =>"00",
               "CLIENT"=>"800",
               "USER"  =>"xxx",    
               "PASSWD"=>"xxx",     
               "LANG"  =>"E");
    $rfc = saprfc_open ($LOGIN);
    $fce = saprfc_function_discover($rfc,"RFC_READ_TABLE");
    if (! $fce )
    {
        echo "Discovering interface of function module failed";
        exit;
    }
    saprfc_import ($fce,"DELIMITER","*");
    saprfc_import ($fce,"NO_DATA","");
    saprfc_import ($fce,"QUERY_TABLE",$table);
    saprfc_import ($fce,"ROWCOUNT","");
    saprfc_import ($fce,"ROWSKIPS","");
    saprfc_table_init ($fce,"FIELDS");
    saprfc_table_init ($fce,"OPTIONS");
    saprfc_table_init ($fce,"DATA");
    saprfc_table_append ($fce,"OPTIONS", $options); 
    $rc = saprfc_call_and_receive ($fce);
    if ($rc != SAPRFC_OK)
    {
        if ($rfc == SAPRFC_EXCEPTION )
        {
            echo ("Exception raised: ".saprfc_exception($fce));
        }
        else
        {
            echo ("Call error: ".saprfc_error($fce));
        }
        exit;
    }
    $data_row = saprfc_table_rows ($fce,"DATA");
    $field_row = saprfc_table_rows ($fce,"FIELDS");
    echo "<div align='center'><p style='font-size:22px;color:midnightblue'>SAP - QUERY TABLE - TFDIR - PHP 7.1.11</p>".
         "<table><tr bgcolor='#dddddd' style='font-size:15px; color:midnightblue;'>".
         "<td>FUNCNAME</td><td>PNAME</td><td>INCLUDE</td><td>FREEDATE</td><td>APPL</td><td>MAND</td><td>FMODE</td><td>HOST</td><td>U_TASK</td><td>PNAME_MAIN</td><td>STEXT</td>";
    for($i=1; $i<=$data_row;$i++)
    {
        $DATA[$i] = saprfc_table_read ($fce,"DATA",$i);
        $ex = explode("*",$DATA[$i]["WA"]);
        echo "<tr style='font-size:12px;'>";
        for ($n=0;$n<=sizeof($ex);$n++)                         
        {
            if($ex[$n] != '')
            {
                echo "<td id=".$i."_".$n.">".$ex[$n]."</td>";
            }
            if(sizeof($ex) == 4 && $n==3)
            {
                echo "<td id=".$i."_".$n.">&nbsp;</td>";
                echo "<td id=".$i."_".$n.">&nbsp;</td>";
                echo "<td id=".$i."_".$n.">&nbsp;</td>";
            }
        }
        echo "</tr>";
    }
    echo "</table></div>";
    //saprfc_function_debug_info($fce);
    saprfc_function_free($fce);
    saprfc_close($rfc);
```

The result is:
[image: all RFC_* functions]

If you need unicode support for example for german etc. you insert this here:

```
$rfc = saprfc_open ($LOGIN);
// enabling the same codepage as SAPGUI - unicode - for  ö,ü,ä etc.
saprfc_set_code_page ($rfc,"4110");
```

Or if you use the E. Koucky framework:

```
$rfc->SetCodePage("4110");
```

Best regards 
Axel Arnold Bangert